# Can applications that have never been published be downloaded?

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

Since the [Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#server-response-codes) documentation has this as a note:

> Additionally, as noted above, applications that are in draft mode (in
>   other words, applicaitons that have been uploaded but have never been
>   published) will return LICENSED for all users, even if not listed as a
>   test user. Since the application has never been offered for download,
>   it is assumed that any users running it must have obtained it from an
>   authorized channel for testing purposes.

I was assuming that it can, but I don't see how it's possible since, to my understanding, apps that has never been published should not be in the Marketplace nor can they be searched for. Or were they referring to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you (the developer) may have sent the .apk directly to some people for testing or reviewing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This means that they're assuming that anything in this state was manually delivered to a tester by the app publisher.  So, if this is your app, you may have given the .apk file to your tester(s) to install manually.

Answer (score 1):

> I was assuming that it can, but I don't see how it's possible since, to my understanding, apps that has never been published should not be in the Marketplace nor can they be searched for.

It actually pretty easy to imagine a way this could be implemented.  When the application checks to see if its licensed it hears back from a server either Yes or No.  Google probably implemented the license server to respond YES for any app that isn't currently in the market.